# mapped drive with FQDN doesn't show all subfolders Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, mapped-drive

if I map network server shared drive as `\\server.domain.name\share$` user see only one subfolder, but if I map as `\\server\share$` end user can see all subfolders.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the user using a local account? Are both computers in the same domain? Try in the target computer to set in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` a DWORD item named `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy with value `1`.

Comment: this is AD environment, user is AD user, OS is same on all computers and this is happening on some not all users and computers

Comment: Can you try the above registry setting on the server?

Comment: And what happens if the user with the problem logs on to a computer that didn't have the problem? Meaning is it dependent on the user account .

Comment: it is dependent of user account; some users see the whole folder structure some just first one subfolder.
BTW did add suggested registry, nothing changed

Comment: My conclusion is that this is a matter of permissions. You could compare between user accounts the have/have-not the problem.